# Are there any Jewish groups that check for a newly married woman's virginity?

Tags: women, marriage, clothing, sexuality, communities

This question follows from: [What are “the tokens of virginity”?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48866/what-are-the-tokens-of-virginity)

Are there any Jewish groups then and now that check for a woman's virginity say by laying out a garment when marriage is first consummated? [cf. [Deut 22:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986#v=17)].

Comment: I've never heard of any. Even in that verse it's only if the husband comes to court to claim she wasn't a virgin.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that claim would have to be after the consummation; the laying out of the garment would thus be done at every marriage's consummation. (Like you, though, I've never heard of such a thing. Maybe some non-_tshb'a"p_ groups?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation about hymens in Judaism has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34327/discussion-on-question-by-fms-are-there-any-jewish-groups-that-check-for-a-newly).

Comment: I know that in the Bukharain community today, it is common for women who are not virgins to have their hymens surgically reconstructed before marriage. It may be because some form of verification by the chosson/husband and/or by the community does indeed take place. I do not know how this squares with her halachic requirement to tell her chosson that she is not a virgin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand in parts of Judea originally (see source below) the friend of the groom and the friend of the bride together checked the sheet.

No bleeding does not mean not a virgin unless we [double checked](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.68.5?with=all) she was not virgin even if she was never with a man but was hit with a stick (i.e. is missing her Hyman for a different reason. [If she was hit with a stick her kesuba is the same an a non-virgin](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.67.5?with=all)).
[The virginity check only helps the husband to lower the amount of the kesuba, or to nullify the wedding, if she admits that she was with another man](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.68.8?with=all).
If I remember correctly in the Talmud it stated the possibility that the blood is blocked by semen

Now (from what I see) usually only the husband checks (if he wants to), and we trust him (she can curse anyone that is lying regarding her (see end of previous link). Since he pays for the meal he would not want to ruin his wife ([Helkas Mechokek 2 and Bais Shmuel 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7700))  .

([If the custom is in that place (even now) that they have 2 witnesses, then if he did not have them, he is not trusted.](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.68.2?with=all))

Ketubot 12a.
[image]
[image]
[image]

See http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.68.1?with=all

Comment: Thank you! Before I select: *No bleeding does not mean not a virgin* Then how to come to the conclusion of whether virgin or not?

Comment: That source says the associate checked what they come in with, not checking the sheet after to see if it's actually bloody.

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if they did not, (I did not say they did) this still answers the question

Comment: @FMS I was wrong it does but only after it is double checked see edits above (I will delete by privius comment)

Comment: @hazoriz Nice! In your refernces, how do you make what you do not want focus on to be translucent? And what is "ketubah" 100 vs. 200?

Comment: @FMS I do not get your first point, regarding 100/ 200 see the first 2 laws [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.67) in short it is a Rabbinic enactment to protect the woman (to make it harder for the husband do divorce her) since originally a husband can devorce his wife for free, they decried that in case of a divorce or death of the husband the wife or her inheritors get money from the husband if she was a virgin (had her Hyman) she should get 200 silver coins (enough to live for a year) if she was not a virgin even if it was only becouse of a stick she would only get 1

Comment: @hazoriz Thank you! When I click on your links, when the page comes up, the referenced text is more vivid. How do you do that?

Comment: @FMS play with it you will figure it out,

Comment: @hazoriz Some of us are technologically challenged :)

Comment: @FMS this is automatic when you click a verse on [sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/), or when you share a reference to a verse through a link

Comment: @mbloch People here are so welcoming and helpful compared to sister site *C.SE* where it can be rough. Thank you mods and all here for your positive spirit here.