# What are the requirements to be killed in Beis Din?

Tags: halacha, beit-din-court

It is my understanding that it is incredibly difficult to be killed in Beis Din - so much so that one that kills once every seven (or seventy) years is a murderous one (Makkos 1:10). What exactly are the requirements that must be fulfilled for a person to be killed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chabad.org summarizes the requirements [Judaism and Capital Punishment](http://www.chabadlive.com/41/judaism-and-capital-punishment/)

> However, Jewish law mandates many caveats to actually securing an
>   execution. First of all there have to be two witnesses to the actual
>   crime. Even strong circumstantial evidence is inadmissible for the
>   purposes of capital punishment. Secondly, the witnesses need to give
>   an official ‘warning’ to the perpetrator that if he commits the
>   offence he is liable to the death penalty. The perpetrator needs to
>   clearly accept this warning and commit the crime within a few seconds
>   of the warning, thus distinguishing the act as utterly premeditated
>   and the sinner completely aware of the consequences. Even if all the
>   above conditions are satisfied there is still no certainty of
>   conviction as the witnesses are subject to very aggressive
>   cross-examination. If certain details of the witnesses testimonies do
>   not correspond or if they are inaccurate in describing the full
>   cirmcustances surrounding the event they can be disqualified and the
>   conviction will not be secured.
>
> Furthermore, according to the Talmud, “any doubts in a capital crimes
>   should always be for the benefit of the accused” (Baba Batra 50B,
>   Sanhedrin 79A). A judge who had argued initially for condemnation can
>   subsequently argue for acquittal, but one who had argued for acquittal
>   cannot not later argue for condemnation. Acquittal in capital cases
>   required only a simple majority of one vote, condemnation required a
>   majority of two.
>
> A ‘guilty’ verdict can be reversed to acquittal if errors are
>   revealed, but new evidence to reverse an ‘innocent’ decision to
>   ‘gulity’ is not accepted!

Note that a **unanimous** declaration of guilty forces the court to let the perpetrator go free because any such case means that not all the facts have been revealed. A judge is not allowed to vote innocent in order to prevent such a unanimous verdict, if he believes the perpetrator guilty.

A court does have certain extra-judicial powers to kill a murderer under certain circumstances and the king can declare the perpetrator subject to the death penalty as a *mored bemalchus* (guilty of treason).

A detailed translation of [Aruch Hashulchan Choshen Mishpat](http://dinonline.org/2016/09/06/emergency-powers-for-beth-din/) gives the details but is too long to summarize here.

As an example we have [The Blood of Thy Brother](http://www.thehalachacenter.org/journal-links/5775/devarim/veschanan/the-blood-of-thy-brother.php)

> The Ohr Samayach in Hilchos Melachim Perek 3 explains that since there
>   is some evidence that the relative was murdered this is sufficient to
>   exonerate the Goel Hadam. The Ohr Somayach compares this to the
>   judicial powers of a Jewish monarch. The Jewish king is allowed to
>   kill someone who rebels against him without the requirements of Bais
>   Din such as two witnesses and a warning. The Jewish king can dispense
>   with these requirements to kill one of his subjects when required. The
>   Ohr Somayach explains that this is because the Jewish king is not
>   punishing the perpetrator but rather he is establishing the authority
>   of a monarch. Respect for the king’s authority uses other extra
>   judicial standards. Similarly, as explained above because of the
>   importance in maintaining the proper respect for the sanctity of
>   Jewish life the extra judicial methods of Goel Hadam or Kipah are used
>   by Bais Din.
>
> The Ketzos in Siman 2 on a theoretical basis points out that although
>   we currently do not have a Bais Din with the authority to administer
>   capital punishment, however, we could perhaps allow a Goel Hadam to
>   avenge the death of a relative. Since in the case of a Goel Hadam it
>   is not a regular punishment but an extra judicial procedure, this
>   could be applicable even when Bais Din itself has no authority to
>   administer capital punishment.

@MonicaCellio has pointed out that the wikipedia article [Stringencies of evidence in capital cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_and_corporal_punishment_in_Judaism#Stringencies_of_evidence_in_capital_cases) actually has the correct list.

> It requires two witnesses who observed the crime. The accused would
>   have been given a chance and if repeated the same crime or any other
>   it would lead to a death sentence. If witnesses had been caught lying
>   about the crime they would be executed.
>
> Two witnesses were required. Acceptability was limited to:
>
> - Adult Jewish men who were known to keep the commandments, knew the written and oral law, and had legitimate professions;
> - The witnesses had to see each other at the time of the sin;
> - The witnesses had to be able to speak clearly, without any speech impediment or hearing deficit (to ensure that the warning and the
>     response were done);
> - The witnesses could not be related to each other or to the accused.
> - The witnesses had to see each other, and both of them had to give a warning (hatra'ah) to the person that the sin they were about to
>     commit was a capital offense;
> - This warning had to be delivered within seconds of the performance of the sin (in the time it took to say, "Peace unto you, my Rabbi and
>     my Master");
>
> In the same amount of time, the person about to sin had to:
>
> - Respond that s/he was familiar with the punishment, but they were going to sin anyway; AND
> - Begin to commit the sin/crime;
> - The Beth Din had to examine each witness separately; and if even one point of their evidence was contradictory - even if a very minor
>     point, such as eye color - the evidence was considered contradictory
>     and the evidence was not heeded;
> - The Beth Din had to consist of minimally 23 judges;
> - The majority could not be a simple majority - the split verdict that would allow conviction had to be at least 13 to 11 in favor of
>     conviction;
> - If the Beth Din arrived at a unanimous verdict of guilty, the person was let go - the idea being that if no judge could find anything
>     exculpatory about the accused, there was something wrong with the
>     court.[12]
> - The witnesses were appointed by the court to be the executioners.
>
> As a result, convictions for capital offense were rare in
>   Judaism.[13][14]